# How can I ignore changes to index.html when compiling with dev/hot-middleware?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-dev-middleware

I am using webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware with html-webpack-plugin. The html plugin is injecting a script dependent upon the environment, but the problem is that this injection triggers another compile, which then causes the html plugin to inject again in an infinite loop.

Does any one know how to tell de/hot-middleware to ignore changes to index.html?